# Why doesn't Mathematica find the obvious clusters?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I run into this problem when analyzing data with obvious clusters. Why doesn't *Mathematica* find the four clusters?

```
stat = RandomChoice[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},1000];
clu = FindClusters[stat];
mclu = Map[Mean, clu]
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {16/33, 16/33, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}

```
clu = FindClusters[stat, 4];
mclu = Map[Mean, clu]
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {120/247, 120/247, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

Comment: What's your version? it works perfectly fine on my computer~

Comment: I use version 9.0.1.0

Answer (score 5):

The problem may be the `Method` of clustering, that is, the clustering algorithm.  Although it isn't immediately obvious from the *Mathematica* documentation, the default method may be *incremental* or *local*, where points are assigned to clusters as they are sequentially considered or in small batches.

Thus for instance, if the first two points are {0,0,0} and {0,0,1} they may be considered by the algorithm to be a *single* cluster, and updated accordingly.

If you use `Method -> "Agglomerate"` this problem vanishes.

Likewise, if you first `Sort` the data, this problem vanishes:

```
stat = RandomChoice[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
   1000];
clu = FindClusters[Sort[stat], 4];
mclu = Map[Mean, clu]
```

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}} *)

Comment: Yes... that's what I stated and coded, but didn't paste the proper code.  Now my answer is fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Agglomerate works but only if you enter the number of clusters in advance. Sort fails to help at least for me. 
Make the data slightly more complicated by adding a few stray values and agglomerate fails as well when a stray value gets its own tiny cluster.

Comment: @Mats Lijendahl Really?  You run the (`Sort`) code I posted and don't get the output I posted?  Then I have no idea what might cause such a problem.

Comment: Yes really. I double checked. May it be that I use version 9?

Comment: I'm using version 10.0.4, but that "explains" nothing...